# Fragmented XML Bulk Load to SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, bulk-load

I have an XML that contain information resulted from scanning systems on different domains. The XML corresponds to the tables in database that are nested as follows:

```
Domains
   Computers
      Volumes
          Folders
              Files
```

My goal is to load the XML into the corresponding tables. 
Since one single XML file would be so large to load into database, I have to chunk it into smaller one. 
How can I format the XMLs so the uploader knows one file is a continue of the last file and it does not generate additional keys for a parent node that is already added.
Does any body any experience doing this? Is this the fastest way to upload? 
Many Thanks!
Here is the code that I use to upload the xml:

```
        static void BulkLoadXML()
    {
        try
        {
            string sPath = @"C:\XMLFiles\";


            string FileName, xsdPath, xmlPath;
            FileName = "TestAuto";

            xmlPath = sPath + FileName + ".xml";
            xsdPath = sPath + FileName + ".xsd";

            SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4 objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4();

            objBL.ConnectionString = @"Provider=sqloledb; server=srv1;database=MyTest;User ID=sa;Password=psw;Connection Timeout=60";

            objBL.ErrorLogFile = "error.xml";
            objBL.KeepIdentity = false;

            objBL.Execute(xsdPath, xmlPath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a a lot of research and here is an idea that partially solves the problem:

http://rakeshbajania.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/prevent-duplicate-entry-when-using-sqlbulkcopy/

So the idea is to define a unique index for tables and set the IGNORE_DUP_KEY to ON.
The only problem is that the DB returns the error and does not upload the children nodes.
In the end, I decided to create temp tables that are loaded by xml chunks one by one and empty them after sending their records to the main tables using stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bulk insert is in order here?  I think in C# you don't even need to write to a text file first.  Use an XMLReader to get the XML into memory and then bulk insert it.  Read the following blog post for info on bulk insert in C#: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I add the C/ code that I am using. Às you mentioned I did not create a text file. However, I have XML files that I need to upload.